# Python make table chart of specific rows of csv without numpy, pandas

Tags: python

I have a csv file that my program allows the user to input, and I want to reproduce a condensed version of this chart, with only specific rows. How would I go about this? I cannot use additional data processing libraries like pandas, numpy, scipy, etc.

```
import csv
import sys
import os

user_input = raw_input("Enter the path of your file: ")

assert os.path.exists(user_input), "I did not find the file at, "+str(user_input)
f = open(user_input,'r+')

print(user_input(rows[2]))

print(user_input(rows[5]))


f.close()
```

Is it possible to do something similar to this code, but rather than simply printing the rows I want, an actual chart is reproduced that I can extract?

Comment: You need to write the code to decide which rows should be printed or how to aggregate the data. You need some logic on this

Comment: Is your question how to get the data, or how to plot the data? I'm assuming it's the second. You say you aren't able to use additional data processing libraries, are you able to use any other libraries? [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) allows you to take iterables and make plots based on them

Comment: It would also help if you provided an example of your data and what you expect your chart output to look like.